# Confidence Intervals in Causal Impact R package

Tags: r, confidence-interval

Can someone explain the confidence intervals plotted by the causal impact R package for me. I don't understand why it would show on the cumulative view?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The cumulative plot contains the cumulative difference between the original time series and the model based counterfactual time series.

Since the counterfactual has uncertainty, the cumulative plot has uncertainty (i.e. conf intervals) as well.